# C# charting - two chart areas with different Y values

Tags: c#, charts, datagridview

Good day nobbles of programming,

I have a question. I made a code to create chart with datagridview as data source with chartarea1.

```
Chart chart1 = new Chart();
        chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1024, 768);


        ChartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
        chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
        chartArea1.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
        chartArea1.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
        chartArea1.AxisX.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);



        chart1.Series.Add(new Series());

        chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName;
        chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName;
        chart1.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;

        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Now i want to create second chartarea within chart1 with same XValueMember but different YValueMember from different datagridview, for example datagridview2. Is it possible to do it?

Thanks in advance.

---

Ok, so i tried this:

```
            Chart chart1 = new Chart();
        ChartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
        Series series1 = new Series();
        chart1.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;

        chartArea1 = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ca1");
        chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
        chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
        chartArea1.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
        chartArea1.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;
        chartArea1.AxisX.Interval = 1;

        series1 = chart1.Series.Add("s1");

        series1.Points.DataBindXY(dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName, dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName);

        series1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

        chart1.SaveImage("chart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Now getting this error:

Y values cannot be data bound to the string object.
Parameter name: yValues

Answer (score 0):

You should not bind to the whole `Chart` then but to the `Series.Points` !

There are many way to use [Chart DataBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd456766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You also should control the `Name` of each `Series` and of the `ChartAreas`; this matters when you want/need to **associate** the 2nd series with the 2nd chartarea.

The preferred/recommended way to add a `ChartArea` or a `Series` is like so:

```
chartArea1 = chart1.ChartAreas.Add("ca1"); // or any other, more useful name

Series series1 = chart1.Series.Add("s1");  // dito
```

The association is done like this:

```
series1.ChartArea  = "ca1";   // note the string!!
```

To bind only one series use..

```
series1.Points.DataBindXY()
```

..or some other overload from the table in the link at the top.